# Segmentation Fault in mergesort program

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<conio.h>

int a[3];

int b[3];

void merge(int a,int mid,int b);      //merge declaration

void mergesort(int i,int j)
{

    int mid;

    while(i<j)
    {

        mid=(i+j)/2;

        mergesort(i,mid);

        mergesort(mid+1,j);

    }

    merge(i,mid,j);

}


void merge(int c,int mid,int l)               //c-first index,l,last index
{

    int k=0;

    int i=c;

    int j=mid+1;

    while((i<mid) && (j<l))
    {

        if(a[i]>a[j])

            b[k++]=a[j++];

        else

            b[k++]=a[i++];
    }

    while(i<mid)
    {

        b[k++]=a[i++];
    }

    while(j<l)

        b[k++]=a[j++];
}

int main()
{

    int i;

    a[0]=3;

    a[1]=2;

    a[2]=4;

    mergesort(0,2);

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)

        printf("the nums are=%d\n",b[i]);
}
```

The expected output is

```
the nums are=2
the nums are=3
the nums are=4
```

Comment: Hint: In `mergesort`, what is `mid`'s value if `i` is equal to `j`? What happens when you pass this value to `merge`?

Comment: Perhaps use a bigger line spacing setting in your editor to avoid double-spaced code like this...

Comment: Another hint: the loop in `mergesort` either runs forever or not at all.

Comment: The while loop in mergersort will execute for ever, it never affects i or j.  Also it would be prudent to check your array indices in merge as I believe this is the source of the SIGSEG

Answer (score 0):

`a` and `b` arrays are 3 members long, but in `merge` you use actual values as indexes